# Multiple filter conditions in scope clause of Rails model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, model

I need to give 2 filter conditions in the scope clause of a model class in my Ruby on Rails code.

I tried this:

```
scope :post_total, -> {where(division: 'PMT', 'key between ? and ?, 3, 7)}
```

division and key are the 2 column names on which I need to the filtering.

So, I need to implement this condition basically:

```
WHERE DIVISION = 'PMT' AND KEY BETWEEN 3 AND 7
```

I am getting an error in my Rails scope condition shown above. What is the correct way to write this scope condition?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with this:

```
scope :post_total, -> { where division: 'PMT', key: 3..7 }
```

Comment: Thanks much for your answer. All the 3 answers were helpful. 

Just a quick question please? For some reason key: 3..7 seems to return key=3 as well. What am I missing here?

Comment: key 4..6 worked for me (4..6 is the equivalent of BETWEEN 3 AND 7)! Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
scope :post_total, -> {where("division = ? AND key BETWEEN ? AND ?", 'PMT', 3,7)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain `where` clauses to use Rails syntax and straight SQL:

```
scope :post_total, -> { where(division: 'PMT').where('key BETWEEN ? AND ?', 3, 7) }
```

Rails will execute this as one query, structured in the desired manner.

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions.